# Uber API map endpoint

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to to get a response from this sandbox endpoint

sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/resource_id/map

instead of getting something like this

{
  "request_id":"b5512127-a134-4bf4-b1ba-fe9f48f56d9d",
  "href":"https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/map"
}

why am I  getting this response?

{
  "message": null,
  "code": "conflict"
}

With the same Bearer token and resource_id I'm getting the right response to this endpoint sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/resource_id/map

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide more details on the steps you are taking (e.g. cURL commands)? As pointed out by Dustin, the first and last URL seem to be the same in your description.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm doing a request via node.js, I'll post it below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the receipt_id is being used instead of the request_id.

The 409 error can happen for a few different reasons: no_drivers_available, missing_payment_method, surge, fare_expired, retry_request, current_trip_exists. Details can be found here - https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests

I don't see the different between the two api requests examples you provided. The sandbox will always show a static map.

In production, maps are only available after a ride has been accepted by a driver and is in the accepted state. Attempting to GET this resource before that will result in a 404 not found error. The sandbox environment provides /v1/sandbox/map for testing, but it provides a static map.

Comment: Thanks @Dustin, the second endpoint is sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/resource_id/receipt. With sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/resource_id/map I'm not getting the static map but the json I posted

Comment: If you have the 'request_receipt' scope you will be able to request receipt. The receipt is not available until after the ride is completee and can be delayed while processing.  For the map endpoint the static map is the url provided in the json payload.